# Error: package 'my_examples_pkg' not found

Tags: roslaunch, ros-kinetic, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a launch file that looks like this:

```
<launch>
    <node pkg="my_examples_pkg" type="cmd_vel_publisher.py" name="cmd_vel_publisher" output="screen" />
</launch>
```

...and a publisher that looks like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist

rospy.init_node('cmd_vel_publisher')
pub = rospy.Publisher('/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=10)
cmd = Twist()
cmd.angular.x = 0
cmd.linear.z = 0

while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    pub.publish(cmd)
    rospy.spin()
```

However, when I try to run the launch file with the following command:

```
roslaunch my_examples_pkg my_examples_pkg.launch
```

I receive the following error:
[my_examples_pkg.launch] is neither a launch file in package [my_examples_pkg] nor is [my_examples_pkg] a launch file name

and when I try to run the individual python publisher file with the following:

```
rosrun my_examples_pkg cmd_vel_publisher.py
```

I receive the following error: [rospack] Error: package 'my_examples_pkg' not found

I'm new to ROS so I apologize if this is a really basic question, but its been plaguing me for a while now.  Most of the resolved questions I see online direct me to do:

```
source devel/setup.bash
```

However, this doesn't resolve my issue as I still receive the errors mentioned above afterwards.  Any help/insights/guidance is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363426/error:-package-%27my_examples_pkg%27-not-found/) by [wynnblevins](https://answers.ros.org/users/60967/wynnblevins/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-10-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wynnblevins](https://answers.ros.org/users/60967/wynnblevins/) on 2020-10-14**:
Oh my gosh, I'm so embarrassed.  Yes I had run catkin_make but the issue was caused by a copy paste error package.xml.  Specifically, the name field was set to the incorrect value.  If you would like to get credit for the answer I will mark your answer as correct!  I so appreciate the help, like I said, I'm very new to ROS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you have a package named `my_examples_pkg`? Is it in your workspace? Has it been built with `catkin_make` or `catkin build`? What is the name of the package in the package.xml and CMakeLists.txt (`<name>` tag and `project()` method respectively)?

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2020-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1